# Powershell script to set multiple variables from a delimited text file

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to read a text file D:\SetCredentials.txt which contains credentials and set the values in variables so that I can use those variables in other script.

File looks like this:

```
serv|16762646t|6879i0i2|9878p989868
```

I want to set the value of a variable in my script below is the code we use in batch script but i want it in powershell script

```
For /F "tokens=1-4 delims=|" %%A in (SetCredentials.txt) do (

set username=%%A
set password=%%B
set servername=%%C
set key=%%D
```

Below is something i wrote, it is just reads and splits the text file  -

```
$credInFile = Get-Content -path "D:\SetCredentials.txt"
$credInFileSplit = credInFile.Split("|")
foreach($i in $credInFileSplit){
 echo $i
}
```

Comment: In your example - change `$credInFileSplit = $credInFile.Split("|")` then look at each element of `$credInFileSplit` e.g. `$credInFileSplit[0]` , `$credInFileSplit[1]` etc

Comment: powershell also supports multi assignment i.e.: `$foo, $bar, $baz = 'foo|bar|baz'.Split('|')`

Comment: Hi @Scepticalist ,How can i set the variables like $username=serv, ,  $password=16762646t from a text file as shown above .

Comment: Hello @SantiagoSquarzon, , how can i read the txt file then?

Comment: Once you know which field has what data in it, just use `Import-Csv -Path 'X:\yourfile.txt' -Header 'Server','Password','UserName','Key' -Delimiter '|'`. Since the fields are unclear to me, that header order may be wrong, only you can tell as it is now..

Answer (score 1):

`Import-CSV` can handle this easily. Assuming that the format is

```
username|password|servername|key
```

you can use

```
$Credential = Import-CSV -Path "D:\SetCredentials.txt" -Header "Username","Password","ServerName","Key" -Delimiter "|"
```

You now have a `PSCustomObject` with four members `Username`, `Password`, `ServerName`, and `Key`, which can be passed as parameters (either as the object entire, or as individual strings, depending on the receiving code) to other cmdlets, advanced functions, or scripts.

(*The `PSCustomObject` is called `$Credential`, and the fields *(*or members*)* are called `$Credential.UserName`, `$Credential.Password`, `$Credential.ServerName`, and `$Credential.Key`. You can use the individual fields as though they were separate variables.*)

(*If the order of the fields is different in the file, rearrange the entries in the `-Header` parameter to match the actuality*)

In general, it's a bad idea to try to replicate a batch file's process identically in PowerShell; there are enough differences that you should think carefully about the intent of the process, and take advantage of the capabilities that PowerShell offers that are not available in batch.

Comment: Hi @Jeff Zeitlin. Thank you ! can you please advise me from where can i learn powersehll

Comment: @BenMartin2 - There are a large number of PowerShell books of all levels out there; you would have to find the ones that suit you best. I have found that in general, the _... for Dummies_ series of books are well-written and present the material clearly; Manning Publications' _Learn ... in a Month of Lunches_ series is also well-written and clear, but in a different style.

Comment: Hi @Jeff , Thanks though but the above code isn't working or I'm not understanding cause the scripting is new to me. Below code from scepticalist is working as expected

Comment: @BenMartin2 - If you're new enough to PowerShell that you're not clear on the concept of objects and members, I'd _strongly_ suggest that you find some good beginners' books on PowerShell - I recommend Manning's _Learn PowerShell in a Month of Lunches_, followed by _Learn PowerShell Scripting in a Month of Lunches_ and _Learn PowerShell Toolmaking in a Month of Lunches_. There will be a lot of overlap in those three books, but together they're a good introduction to PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variables directly from array elements:

```
$credInFile = Get-Content -path "D:\SetCredentials.txt"
$credInFileSplit = $credInFile.Split("|")

$username=$credInFileSplit[0]
$password=$credInFileSplit[1]
$servername=$credInFileSplit[2]
$key=$credInFileSplit[3]
```